# In Python, decorate two methods with the same name to distinguish them

Tags: python, decorator, metaclass

I am writing a framework to be used by people who know some Python. I have settled on some syntax, and it makes sense to me and them to use something like this, where Base is the Base class that implements the framework.

```
class A(Base):
    @decorator1
    @decorator2
    @decorator3
    def f(self):
        pass

    @decorator4
    def f(self):
        pass

    @decorator5
    def g(self)
        pass
```

All my framework is implemented via Base's metaclass. This setup is appropriate for my use case, because all these user-defined classes have a rich inheritance graph. I expect the user to implement some of the methods, or just leave it with `pass`. Much of the information that the user is giving here is in the decorators. This allows me to avoid other solutions where the user would have to monkey-patch, give less structured dictionaries, and things like that.

My problem here is that `f` is defined twice by the user (with good reason), and this should be handled by my framework. Unfortunately, by the time this gets to the metaclass'`__new__` method, the dictionary of attributes contains only one key `f`. My idea was to use yet another decorator, such as `@duplicate` for the user to signal this is happening, and the two `f`'s to be wrapped differently so they don't overwrite each other. Can something like this work?

Comment: What is supposed to happen if I do `A().f()`?

Comment: How can defining `f` twice have a good reason -- what does it mean or is supposed to do?

Comment: As I said, this is for a framework. The class A will never be instantiated. Its existence is important however because it's a way for the user to communicate to the program that "something like `A`" should exist. From there, my framework figures out about the different versions of `f`s and create various "proper" `A`-like classes. If you want, this is a way to do aspect-oriented programming, structured in a more classical object-oriented way.

Answer (score 1):

You should use a namespace to distinguish the different `f`s.

Heed the advice of the "Zen of Python":

> Namespaces are one honking great idea -- let's do more of those!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you could, but only with an ugly hack, and only by storing the function with a *new* name.

You'd have to use the [`sys._getframe()` function](http://docs.python.org/library/sys.html#sys._getframe) to retrieve the local namespace of the calling frame. That local namespace is the class-in-construction, and adding items to that namespace means they'll end up in the class dictionary passed to your metaclass.

The following retrieves that namespace:

```
callframe = sys._getframe(1)
namespace = callframe.f_locals
```

`namespace` is a dict-like object, just like `locals()`. You can now store *something* in that namespace (like `__function_definitions__` or similar) to add extra references to the functions.

Comment: Near the end of the section titled [Descriptive: Naming Styles](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#descriptive-naming-styles) in [PEP 8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/), it says "`__double_leading_and_trailing_underscore__`: "magic" objects or attributes that live in user-controlled namespaces. E.g. `__init__`, `__import__` or `__file__`. **Never** invent such names; only use them as documented", so storing the _something_ in the namespace with that name doesn't sound like good advice.

Comment: @martineau: yup, but tradition has it that many projects use the double-underscore convention (at their own, *low*, risk) anyway. Since the metaclass is going to process the whole thing anyway (presumably removing the extra value) this should not present much of a problem.

Comment: There are several levels of user in what I want to do. I am using Python, but also have users myself. I want the user to give me a highly decorated class diagram, except for this minor difference that multiple method definitions should be allowed. It makes sense to me that I need to reach into the calling frame, the only alternative I see is to modify the Python interpreter...

Comment: @user1199915: How are calls to the functions differentiated, by the type of argument(s) like C++? If so perhaps you can mangle the function's name based on them like it does.

Comment: @Martijn Pieters: Whether it's low risk within a project that important, but if it's part of an interface especially one exposed to users, it's best always avoided.

Answer (score 0):

You might be thinking Java - methods overloading and arguments signature - but this is Python and you cannot do this. The second f() will override the first f() and you end up with only one f(). The namespace is a dictionary and you cannot have duplicated keys.